# Como carregar recarregar pagina quando selecionar item dropdownlist da lista jquery passando parametros?

Tags: jquery, html, java-ee

Eu tenho um select

```html
<select id="selecao" name="tipoLocal">
  
  <option value="casa">Casa</option>
  
  <option value="predio">Predio</option>
  
  <option value="predio">Terreno</option>
  
</select>
```

É possível em jquery recarregar pagina passando como parametro assim que selecionar um item do select, sem precisar clicar em nenhum botão, apenas quando seleciono uma opção já carrega a url "www.exemplo.com/{parametro}", onde essa url repassa pra um controller em java? Como fazer?

Comment: Bom não sei se entendi direito, você quer chamar uma controller quando selecionar algum item do combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar o evento [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do jQuery e passaria o valor do item selecionado para um `location.href`. Ficaria assim o seu exemplo:

```js
$('#selecao').change(function(){
var parametro = $(this).find(':selected').val()

 location.href = 'www.exemplo.com/' + parametro;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selecao" name="tipoLocal">
  
  <option value="casa">Casa</option>
  
  <option value="predio">Predio</option>
  
  <option value="terreno">Terreno</option>
  
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com ajax também.

```
 $("#combo").change(function(){

        var value = $('#combo :selected').text();

         $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                   url: 'controller/metodo',
                   cache: false,
                   data: value,
                   dataType: '',
                   contentType: '',
                   success: function () {

                   }
         });
    })
```